# Changing in a header file which is included in all modules of a large project

Tags: c, compilation

I have a large project, that takes about half an hour to compile.

This project consists of many modules, but there is a certain header file that contains data shared between all modules.

Currently, I am making major changes in this header file, and every time I am trying to compile and run the project to make sure that everything is going fine, it takes huge amount of time to be compiled (because this header file is included in all modules).

Is there anyway to overcome this large compilation time ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider not structuring your project like that.

Your file probably contains a number of strings, integers etc. Put these into a single `.c` file, and either provide functions to read them, or use `extern int foo;` etc. in the header.

If you can't do that:

- `make -jN` will run a parallel `make` with up to `N` processes (twice the number of CPU cores seems to work well).
- Don't recompile after every change. Recompile when you have made lots of changes.
- Get a faster computer, or use [`distcc`](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/).
- Does the header file *really* need to be included into *every* file? Can it be broken up so only some files include some of it?
- If so, consider refactoring your code so it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you.
But what is "distcc"

Comment: `distcc` allows `cc` (or `gcc`) to be run transparently on multiple machines across the LAN or the internet. I've added a link.

Comment: No, I have tried to break it up, but its contents are used in all modules :(